# need help setting a simple typescript preact app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, sass, preact

I am new to preact and I am trying to a setup a simple app with typescript in preact. Their default and typescript templates contain unnecessary things like jest and testing which I don't need. They have another template called "simple" but that only comes in js.

Is there any way to add typescript to the simple template of preact?

My goal is to get a template similar to the preact "simple" template with typescript and scss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full disclosure, I'm a maintainer of Preact-CLI and those templates.

You can simply switch `.js` files to `.ts` in the simple template and have TypeScript support, nothing else is needed. However, I'd caution against that route as the simple template is missing key fundamentals like file system-based code splitting, routing, some direction on how to handle assets, etc.

I'd recommend instead to simply remove the things from the TS template that you don't want. Remove `jest` (and associated packages) from the `package.json` if you don't want them.

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried changing .js to .ts but that didn't work and gave a lot of errors. Someone then recommended to use vite (preact-ts) template and that worked. Do you know if using this method will have the things you mentioned above (routing, code splitting, etc)? Or will I need to do what you said with removing the unwanted things from the TS template of preact-cli?

Comment: "lot of errors" gives me nothing to go on. If you were using JSX, then those files would need to be `.tsx`, for what it's worth. Vite and Preact-CLI are two completely different build tools; it's far less opinionated and you'll need to set up things like code splitting, prerendering, critical CSS inlining, etc. yourself if you want them. That can be a good or bad thing, just depends on your wants.